# Question on Matplotlib bar plot with a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to create a bar chart with SALES_COV_TYPE as X and ID_ev as Y. I would like to have both the bars in different colors. Rename X axis values, and also rename the X label in legend to something else as can be seen in the image link. Change Id_ev to 'Visits'.

This is my attempt at it and I'm not satisfied with it.

```
    data = {'SALES_COV_TYPE':[84.0,88.0], 'ID_ev':[2360869,882791]}

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)

    df.plot(kind='bar',y='ID_ev',x='SALES_COV_TYPE')

    ax=plt.gca()

    my_xticks = ['CAM','GAM']

    ax.set_xticklabels(my_xticks)

    ax.set_xlabel('Sales Coverage Type')

    ax.set_ylabel('Number of Customer Visits')
```

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhQ1k.png)

I want to create the bar chart using fig, ax method so that when I create subplots in future this becomes a template for me, but I am not being able to get it done. I would not like to use the pandas wrapper for matplotlib if possible. What do you all suggest?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this:

```
data = {'SALES_COV_TYPE':[84.0,88.0], 'ID_ev':[2360869,882791], 'SALES_COV_CLASS':['CAM','GAM']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
colors = ['green', 'red']
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(4,3))
ax.bar(df['SALES_COV_CLASS'], df['ID_ev'], color = colors)
ax.set_title('Title')
ax.set_xlabel('Sales Coverage Type')
ax.set_ylabel('Number of Customer Visits')

plt.show()
```

I find it easier to add a column with the name of the group, that way you don't need to reindex the x axis to remove the empty columns.